# Orthogonality issue in scipy's legendre polynomials

Tags: python, scipy, polynomials, orthogonal

I recently stumbled upon a curious issue concerning the `scipy.special.legendre()` ([scipy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.legendre.html)). The legendre polynomials should be pairwise orthogonal. However, when I calculate them over a range `x=[-1,1]` and build the scalar product of two polynomials of different degree I don't always get zero or values close to zero. Do I misinterpret the functions behaviour?
In the following I have written a short example, which produces the scalar product of certain pairs of legendre polynomials:

```
from __future__ import print_function, division
import numpy as np 
from scipy import special
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create range for evaluation
x = np.linspace(-1,1, 500)

degrees = 6
lp_array = np.empty((degrees, len(x)))

for n in np.arange(degrees):
    LP = special.legendre(n)(x)
    # alternatively:
    # LP = special.eval_legendre(n, x)
    lp_array[n, ] = LP
    plt.plot(x, LP, label=r"$P_{}(x)$".format(n))

plt.grid()
plt.gca().set_ylim([-1.1, 1.1])
plt.legend(fontsize=9, loc="lower right")
plt.show()
```

The plot of the single polynomials actually looks fine:
[image: Legendre polynomials from degree 0 to 5]

But if I calculate the scalar products manually – multiply two legendre polynomials of different degree elementwise and sum them up (the 500 is for normalization)...

```
for i in range(degrees):
    print("0vs{}: {:+.6e}".format(i, sum(lp_array[0]*lp_array[i])/500))
```

... I get the following values as output:

```
0vs0: +1.000000e+00
0vs1: -5.906386e-17
0vs2: +2.004008e-03
0vs3: -9.903189e-17
0vs4: +2.013360e-03
0vs5: -1.367795e-16
```

The scalar product of the first polynomial with itself is (as to be expected) equal one, and half of the other results are almost zero, but there are some values in the order of `10e-3` and I have no idea why. I also tried the `scipy.special.eval_legendre(n, x)` function – same result :-\

Is this a bug in the `scipy.special.legendre()` function? Or do I do something wrong? I am looking for constructive responds :-)

cheers,
Markus

Comment: thanks for integrating the image :-)

Comment: Hmm, ok. I don't really understand why my approach doesn't work correctly but yeah, it definitely makes sense to integrate the polynomial product. Thanks for this point.

Comment: Your integration approach is not exact. `10^{-3} ~ 1/500` is the order of magnitude of error you'd expect with 500 points.

Comment: Use more points, or use `scipy.integrate.quad`.  E.g. `quad(lambda x: special.legendre(0)(x)*special.legendre(2)(x), a=-1, b=1)`

Comment: Concerning my actual problem (in statistics): here I have a 126 dimensional problem which forces my legendre polynomials to be of length 126. So, that is obviously too short for `scipy.special.legendre` to result in proper orthogonal polynomials. However, this leads to varying variance values when calculating the covariance matrix, depending on how many legendre polynomials I take in account. Is there a way to handle this problem?

Comment: Why must the Legendre polys be sampled at only 126 points? What does the number of samples have to do with the dimensionality of the problem? (If the problem were approached analytically, wouldn't the polys be functions from [-1, 1] (an infinite number of points) to the reals?)

Comment: My dataset is of shape (100,60) and the empirical covariance matrix therefore of shape (100,100). For reducing the dimensions by projection of the data onto legendre polynomials one can show by least square regression that the estimator of the covariance matrix is `S' = P.dot(S_emp).dot(P.T)` with `P = inv(np.dot(G, G.T)).dot(G.T)` and with `G`containing the legendre polynomials column wise. For consistent matrix multiplication `G` hast to be of length `100` and so the legendre polynomials have to be.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no higher resolution of the data, as they are yearly means of temperature values over a time period of 100 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have commented, you're going to get some error, since you're performing an in-exact integral.

But you can reduce the error by doing the integral as best you can. In your case, you can still improve your sampling points to make the integral more exact. When sampling, use the "midpoint" of the intervals instead of the edges:

```
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, nx, endpoint=False)
x += 1 / nx   # I'm adding half a sampling interval
              # Equivalent to x += (x[1] - x[0]) / 2
```

This gives quite a lot of improvement! If I use the old sampling method:

```
nx = 500
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, nx)

degrees = 7
lp_array = np.empty((degrees, len(x)))

for n in np.arange(degrees):
    LP = special.eval_legendre(n, x)
    lp_array[n, :] = LP

np.set_printoptions(linewidth=120, precision=1)
prod = np.dot(lp_array, lp_array.T) / x.size
print(prod)
```

This gives:

```
[[  1.0e+00  -5.7e-17   2.0e-03  -8.5e-17   2.0e-03  -1.5e-16   2.0e-03]
 [ -5.7e-17   3.3e-01  -4.3e-17   2.0e-03  -1.0e-16   2.0e-03  -1.1e-16]
 [  2.0e-03  -4.3e-17   2.0e-01  -1.3e-16   2.0e-03  -1.0e-16   2.0e-03]
 [ -8.5e-17   2.0e-03  -1.3e-16   1.4e-01  -1.2e-16   2.0e-03  -1.0e-16]
 [  2.0e-03  -1.0e-16   2.0e-03  -1.2e-16   1.1e-01  -9.6e-17   2.0e-03]
 [ -1.5e-16   2.0e-03  -1.0e-16   2.0e-03  -9.6e-17   9.3e-02  -1.1e-16]
 [  2.0e-03  -1.1e-16   2.0e-03  -1.0e-16   2.0e-03  -1.1e-16   7.9e-02]]
```

Error terms are ~10^-3.

But using the "midpoint sampling scheme", I get:

```
[[  1.0e+00  -2.8e-17  -2.0e-06  -3.6e-18  -6.7e-06  -8.2e-17  -1.4e-05]
 [ -2.8e-17   3.3e-01  -2.8e-17  -4.7e-06  -2.7e-17  -1.1e-05  -4.1e-17]
 [ -2.0e-06  -2.8e-17   2.0e-01  -5.7e-17  -8.7e-06  -2.3e-17  -1.6e-05]
 [ -3.6e-18  -4.7e-06  -5.7e-17   1.4e-01  -2.1e-17  -1.4e-05  -5.3e-18]
 [ -6.7e-06  -2.7e-17  -8.7e-06  -2.1e-17   1.1e-01   1.1e-17  -2.1e-05]
 [ -8.2e-17  -1.1e-05  -2.3e-17  -1.4e-05   1.1e-17   9.1e-02   7.1e-18]
 [ -1.4e-05  -4.1e-17  -1.6e-05  -5.3e-18  -2.1e-05   7.1e-18   7.7e-02]]
```

Errors are now ~10^-5 or even 10^-6, which is much better!

Comment: First, thank you very much for your answer. 
Just for understanding: By adding `1/nx` you just shift all the "ticks" of `x` by half of an intervall. After that you actually only do a scalar product of all legendre polynomials with each other, right? Why do you get an improvement in the error terms then? Because you don't increase the number of sampling points. Only the legendre polynomials are evaluated on slightly different positions.